# How to change a text in text area when the button is clicked?

Tags: android

I'm developing a question game and I want to change the question in text area when user clicks the button (YES/NO) so user have their next question and game proceed.

```
xml code for the button :


 <Button
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Yes"
  android:id="@+id/btnuserRYes"
  android:textStyle="bold"
  android:textSize="16dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
  android:typeface="serif"
  android:background="@drawable/yesbutton"
  android:onClick="Yesbtnclicked" 
/>

Xml Code for another button:
<Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/category2"
            android:id="@+id/btnanimal"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btncricket"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblofflinemode"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:height="50dp"
            android:onClick="onClickanimal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:width="120dp"
            android:typeface="serif" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `OnClickListener()` to your YES/NO button

```
  btnuserRYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
          //change the text of any text area
    }
  });
```

Comment: already did that man.. but still my app crashes when i pressed the button

Comment: Can you please paste the relevant code and the exception logs?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to think about architecture and structure of your questions, answers to make quality app.

If says about your question:

```
userbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnuserRYes);
userbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //save answer to database
                //...
                //change text of UI elements
                //you can load info from database
                userbutton.setText("Your next text");
            }
        });
```